# jquery code that selects on the second option value

Tags: jquery

How to select the second option value in jquery and when it is focused on that option value, I have to trigger a console.log() command.

Comment: What's wrong with my question.

Comment: Your post lacks MVCE check our [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section

Answer (score 0):

By default bxslider already have the responsive option as true.
Regarding the width it will have the same it's container.

Regarding fixing the height you can set **adaptiveHeight** as true. This will adjust the height to the height of the current slide.

For example:

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
adaptiveHeight: true
});
```

Everything is described here: http://bxslider.com/options

Regards,

André